# Why does the extended version of the Lato font have different proportions to the original version?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, fontlab-studio

I have downloaded Lato from Google Fonts, which is the original version. Lato was later extended to include more characters, and this version can be found at latofonts.com (among other locations). I've tried both of them in my website but they have completely different proportions. I prefer the original proportions but I would also like the utilize the additional characters in the extended version.

The following image shows the woff2 files rendered on Google Chrome. The top line is the original Lato font. The bottom line is the extended version. Notice that the extended version characters are taller. In particular, look at the difference in the 'r' and the 'o'. The 'r' actually gets narrower.

[image]

Is this a deliberate design change or is something going wrong here?

Comment: It's not uncommon for fonts with the *same name* to have variations between *foundries*. This is why *some* foundries place identifiers in the names, i.e. ITC, Adobe, FF, BT, etc.

Comment: I didn't realize they're from different foundries? I have loaded each 'r' into FontForge and they do indeed have different proportions in there as well. I'm guessing it is a deliberate design change.

Comment: It might be that the larger lower case letters are easier to read at small sizes on the web, or just renders better on-screen. This is just a guess though.

Comment: Font *names* can't be copyrighted.. So, every foundry can create their own version of a font and name it Lato. It's the glyphs and artwork which *can* be copyrighted. So, even though a name may be identical that rarely means the glyphs are identical between foundries. this is why you find Adobe Garamond, ITC Garamond, Linotype Garamond, FF Garamond, etc. And they all have very minute differences. Google and Adobe *both* have a version of Lato, chances are specific builds were *licensed* by those companies.